# wissen vs kennen

Tags: verb-choice

After having read [Wissen & Kennen](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/30225/wissen-kennen), I'm still wondering about what to do here:

> Ich habe ein Vorstellungsgespräch morgen. Ich weiß/kenne den genauen Zeitpunkt nicht.

In English, you'd never say "I'm not familiar with the exact time point", which goes against "kennen". But in German, "wissen" usually takes a phrase, which goes agaist "wissen". Any help?

Comment: I would say both are correct..

Comment: "Der genaue Zeitpunkt ist mir nicht bekannt". Aber "Zeitpunkt" passt hier nicht so genau.

Answer (score 2):

Aus dem Handgelenk würde ich sagen:

- **wissen** = eine Information haben
- **kennen** = a) (persönlich) kennengelernt haben b) Erfahrungen gemacht haben mit

Den fraglichen Satz würde ich so sagen:

> 2 Ich habe morgen ein Vorstellungsgespräch, aber ich weiß nicht genau, wann.

Ich würde weder sagen:

> 3 ?Ich kenne die Uhrzeit nicht, wann der Termin ist.

und auch nicht:

> 4 ?Ich kenne den Zeitpunkt nicht, wann der Termin ist.

Mit "Zeitpunkt" wäre dieser Satz 'etwas weniger falsch', aber trotzdem für mein Gefühl nicht richtig.

Es ist übrigens seltsam, dass jemand einen Termin ohne Zeitangabe hat. Ist es inzwischen üblich, dass man zum Vorstellungsgespräch eingeladen wird und wartet, bis man aufgerufen wird? Ansonsten würde man eher sagen:

> 5 Ich habe morgen ja mein Vorstellungsgespräch bei ... Die Uhrzeit hab ich dummerweise vergessen.

Man kann auch sagen:

> 6 Ich weiß (nicht), wann der Termin ist.

oder

> 7 Ich weiß nicht, wann der Termin sein wird.

oder noch besser

> 8 Ich weiß nicht, auf wieviel Uhr sie [= die Einlader] den Termin gelegt haben.

oder

> 9 Ich weiß ärgerlicherweise nicht, wann ich den Termin habe.

Aus dem Handgelenk lässt sich das jedoch nicht beantworten. Interessant sind Sätze als 'Quasi-Minimalpaare' der Semantik wie

> 10a Ich weiß die Antwort (nicht) > < 10b Ich kenne die Antwort (nicht).

oder

> 11a Ich weiß seinen Namen > < 11b Ich kenne seinen Namen

oder

> 12 Ich weiß, wovon du da redest > < 13 Ich kenne das. (Kennst du das auch?)

Ich komme darauf zurück, ist eine sehr interessante Frage.

Answer (score 1):

> Ich weiß den Zeitpunkt nicht.
>
> Ich kenne den Zeitpunkt nicht.

A general rule is, if you (don't) know which item is meant, you should use *wissen*. *Kennen* in contrary means you have/haven't further information about the item.

In the example above, *wissen* sticks to that rule, but *kennen* is also okay as you cannot expect to have further information about a date. It's just a date. Consider:

> Fahrt ihr an die See? – Ja, vielleicht nach Binz, das weiß ich noch nicht.

*Do you go to the sea? – Yes, maybe to Binz, I don't know yet (whether that's our destination).*

> Fahrt ihr an die See? – Ja, vielleicht nach Binz, das kenne ich noch nicht.

*Do you go to the sea? – Yes, maybe to Binz, I don't know it (Binz) yet.*

Comment: Thanks. However, your examples are probably not similar enough. In *Ja, vielleicht nach Binz, das weiß ich noch nicht*, the demonstrative *das* refers to the whole thing *Ja, vielleicht nach Binz*, whereas in *Ja, vielleicht nach Binz, das kenne ich noch nicht*, the demonstrative *das* refers to *Binz*. In my example, on the contrary, the object is exactly the same both grammatically and semantically, namely, *der Zeitpunkt*.

Comment: Yes, and that's the reason you can use both *wissen* and *kennen* in your example, with exactly the same meaning. They are meant to tell apart those two cases, if there isn't a difference, you cannot dig out one.